# Is it possible to migrate from Magento 1 Enterprise to Magento 2 Open Source?

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I'm looking to migrate from Magento Enterprise 1.14.2 to Magento Open Source 2.2.2.

Having looked at Magento's `data-migration-tool`, I noticed an absence of any "commerce to open source" migration paths, for obvious reasons (Magento doesn't want paying customers to downgrade).

So is it possible to directly migrate from v1 Enterprise to v2 Open Source? Has anyone successfully done this?

Comment: FYI: someone suggested an edit to this question, changing "Open Source" to "Community Edition". Magento 2 no longer uses the "Community Edition" name. It's called "Magento 2 Open Source."

Comment: if you have lots of custom code and extensions, you wont be able to migrate it automatically.